# How can I resolve the "error decoding from json: illegal base64 data at input byte 0" for Kubernetes secrets?

Tags: json, kubernetes, yaml

I currently am working on adding a new secret for our project which usually stores secrets in Kubernetes. I pretty much mimicked all the other secrets that I could find, so it would seem that everything should be correct. However, it's not working and giving me `for: "kubernetes/template/secrets.yml": error decoding from json: illegal base64 data at input byte 0`. I'm not sure if this is an issue from within Kubernetes or from my script.

The secrets file looks something like this:

*secrets.yml*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  …
type: Opaque
data:
  SECRET_A: {SECRET_A}
  SECRET_B: {SECRET_B}
```

*deployk8.sh*

```
set -e

sed -i "s,{SECRET_A},${SECRET_A},g" kubernetes/template/secrets.yml
sed -i "s,{SECRET_B},${SECRET_B},g" kubernetes/template/secrets.yml # The new one

kubectl --record --namespace=${...} --token ${...} --cluster ${...} apply -f kubernetes/template/secrets.yml
```

When I run `kubectl get secret my-secret -o json`, I get something similar to this:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "data": {
        "SECRET_A": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456",
        "SECRET_B": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcd"
    },
    "kind": "Secret",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"data\":{\"SECRET_A\":\"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456\"},\"kind\":\"Secret\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"kubernetes.io/change-cause\":\"kubectl apply --record=true --namespace=ns --token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --cluster=my_cluster --filename=kubernetes/template/secrets.yml\"},\"labels\":{\"app\":\"my-app\",\"env\":\"dev\"},\"name\":\"my-app-dev\",\"namespace\":\"ns\"},\"type\":\"Opaque\"}\n",
            "kubernetes.io/change-cause": "kubectl apply --record=true --namespace=ns --token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx--cluster=my_cluster --filename=kubernetes/template/secrets.yml"
        },
        "creationTimestamp": "20XX-XX-XXTXX:XX:XXZ",
        "labels": {
            "app": "my-app",
            "env": "dev"
        },
        "name": "my-app-dev",
        "namespace": "ns",
        "resourceVersion": "0000000000",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/ns/secrets/my-app-dev",
        "uid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    },
    "type": "Opaque"
}
```

The entire error looks something like this:

```
  kubectl --record --namespace=${...} --token ${...} --cluster ${...} apply -f 
  kubernetes/template/secrets.yml
  Error from server: error when applying patch:
  [inset output from above, but with:
    {\"SECRET_A\":\"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456\",\"SECRET_B\":\"$SECRET_B\"}]
  to:
  [transformed output from above, but with:
    Object: &{map["apiVersion":"v1" "data":map["SECRET_A":"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456\" "SECRET_B":"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcd"]]
```

I would really appreciate any help in figuring this out!

Comment: @curiosa it's just a place holder and not the real value. Nonetheless, I could put in both of these values above, and still get the same error for SECRET_B (and not SECRET_A).

Comment: I hope its not too trivial to suggest to have a look at secrets.yml after the change?

Comment: Go for https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize

Comment: Another error I came across in messing with the code a bit, is `error validating data: ValidationError(Secret.data.SECRET_B): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.Secret.data: got "map", expected "string";` It seems to come from the `secrets.yml` file I've added above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **stringData** field like described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#secret-v1-core). That way you do not have to base64 the input. Note the field is write-only.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a resolution to my issue. It turns out that my environmental variable that I was pulling from that changed (i.e. `SECRET_B` should have been just been `B`). So, technically, `SECRET_B` didn't exist. Changing this managed to fix my issue. Thank you to everyone who tried to help!